# Missing Clickonce prerequisites in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I have installed Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0.  It appears as a Clickonce Prerequisite in Visual Studio 2010 but in Visual Studio 2013 Professional It has the yellow triangle next to it and an error is generated when I build my project.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I found a work around.  I went to the bootstrapper directory located here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\

Visual Studio 2013 looks here for the bootstrapper packages: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\

Inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\  I found the VBPowerPacks folder and copied it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\

Not sure why VBPowerPacks does not automatically install in all Bootstrapper folders.  That would have saved me a great deal of time.

Comment: Microsoft can only publish so much with VS, and they tend to drop things that they think are no longer used. Copying it from a previous version is the exact right thing to do.