# I am trying to publish a click once application I am missing prerequisites

Tags: c#, clickonce, prerequisites

[image: Missing Prerequisites]

I am wondering where I can get these from. Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046760/missing-clickonce-prerequisites-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015, though it did get rid of the prerequisites problem I was having. I am not experiencing a whole new issue.

I will create a new question and mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages